# How can I print list elements separated by line feeds in Perl?

Tags: perl

What is the easiest way to print all a list's elements separated by line feeds in Perl?

Comment: no need to get fancy. go through the elements, print them out followed by \n. easy enough?

Comment: I would actually argue the contrary position; that perl was specifically created to get, stay and flaunt 'fancy'. For reference I recommend: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-zpOMYRi0w

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
print "$_\n" for @list;
```

In Perl 5.10:

```
say for @list;
```

Another way:

```
print join("\n", @list), "\n";
```

Or (5.10):

```
say join "\n", @list;
```

Or how about:

```
print map { "$_\n" } @list;
```

Comment: I tend to add a dummy element at the end of the list: `print join("\n", @list, '')`

Comment: That works for this case, but not so well if you want to join it with something other than newlines (which I occasionally do), and if you change your mind on how you want the output format to look, doing that just makes it take a little extra work.

Comment: @ChrisLutz Why is the result different when I am using print join("\n", "@list"), "\n";  ### Double commas before and after "@list"?

Answer (score 10):

Why not abuse Perl's global variables instead

```
local $\ = "\n";
local $, = "\n";
print @array;
```

If you get excited for unnecessary variable interpolation feel free to use this version instead:

```
local $" = "\n";
print "@array\n";
```

Comment: Of course, we _could_ just make this global variable abuse safe and sanitary: `sub arrprint (\@;$$) { my @a = @{shift()}; local $\ = @_ ? shift : $\; local $, = @_ ? shift : $,; print @$aref; }` (code untested)

Answer (score 8):

```
print join "\n", @list;
```

Comment: This won't print a newline at the end, which isn't bad on Windows but will look ugly on *nix systems.

Comment: And? The question specifically says *separated by*.

Comment: Most people want newlines printed at the ends of the things they print. That's why most languages provide a function that do exactly that. Even C does it with `puts()`.